# Loading Images From Tomcat

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, jointjs

Basically, what I'm doing is saving a png image in Tomcat and then attempting to load it from the javascript side. Everything is in place but for some reason the image is not being loaded.

Here's a more detailed explanation:

1) I receive the image in Base64. I decode it into png and store it in a byte array:

```
byte[] data = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(icons.get(key));
```

2) I store the image in Tomcat using `user.dir` system property:

```
imageFolder= createFolder(FileUtils.getFile(System.getProperty("user.dir")),"icon","image");
```

The resulting url from the line above is this one:

```
D:\tools\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin\icon\image
```

And this image is stored there (I checked the Tomcat folder).

Here's where it gets a little confusing. For some reason, the image is not being loaded even though I'm absolutely certain that I'm correctly "calling" it from JS side:

```
        image: {
            'xlink:href': '/icon/image/' + nodeOptions.icon + '.png',
            width: 21 * imageScale, //Default size for image is 21x21
            height: 21 * imageScale
        }
```

In debugger, the image is being loaded with the correct name (which is the variable `key`in the aforementioned java code).

Is it because the image is stored in the bin folder of Tomcat and there are certain rights that I'm unaware of to fetch anything from that folder? If so how can I change the image folder to be the webapp folder of Tomcat? Keep in mind that I have to keep using the system property `user.dir`in the java code.

Comment: _Keep in mind that I have to keep using the system property user.dirin the java code_ Why ? CATALINA_BASE environment variable was made for this. Maybe should you store the file in the catalina temp dir and implement a filter which reads and sends files from there.

Comment: @EugèneAdell I would recommend against storing user file-uploads in `CATALINA_BASE`... if you undeploy the application, it will delete all your files.

Comment: When you say "isn't loading", what do you mean? What *does* it do?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I agree, there are better places for storing files without compromising security or application behaviour, but they need an environment variable or an entry in the web.xml (they have a cost).

Comment: Mounting a directory to be served by the `DefaultServlet` is pretty easy in every currently-supported version of Tomcat. And it's much safer (won't delete your files) and robust (DefaultServlet is much better code than most people would be ableabel to write themselves).